# How do I setup Yahoo Small Business mail to I can send email from OSX Mail?

Tags: apple-mail, yahoo-mail

I've tried setting up Yahoo Small Business email account in OSX Mail, and so far I can receive but cannot send email. For outgoing email I use the following settings:

- Server: smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com
- Port: 465
- Use SSL
- Use Authentication with Password.

I followed the instructions [here](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/bizmail/pop/pop-33.html). Can anyone help please?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: There is no error message. It just keeps trying and trying to send the message. Sometimes it would ask me for my password again, which is the same password that I entered for the POP settings.

Answer (score 0):

Click File | Add Account.
Enter the following:

```
Full Name - The name you want on your outgoing email.
Email address - Your full Business Mail email address.
Password - Your Business Mail password.
```

Click Continue.
In the "Incoming Mail Server" screen, enter the following:

```
Account Type - POP
Description - A descriptive name for your account.
Incoming Email Server - pop.bizmail.yahoo.com
User Name - Your full Business Mail email address.
Password - Your Business Mail password.
```

Click the Continue button